# Not able to get behave.ini url

Tags: python-behave

Hy I am not able to retrive the url from the behave.ini file.

I am using this function to retrive value from behave.ini file:

def get_value_from_ini(context, key):
This function returns the configuration value from behave.ini.

```
Args:
    context (Context): The default object is available throughout the behave framework.
    key (Any): Key in the key-value pair from the behave.ini.

Returns:
    Value (Enum): Value in the key-value pair from the behave.ini
"""

return context.config.userdata.get(key)`
```

IN BEHAVE.INI file:
[behave.userdata]
URL = www.etc.com`